# open a pop up window with image from device

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to android devlopment,

what I want to do is, I have a list of photos I want to display on a map,
for each photo I will display a marker, and when clicking on the marker the photo itself will popup.

what I have done so far is to open the map and show the markers according to the photos location, I have now implmented a click listener to show the image

this is my code:

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                // get relevent photo from map
                Photo photo = photoMarkers.get(marker);
                if (photo == null){
                    Log.d("Journee", "photo is null");
                    return false;
                }
                photoPopUp(photo);
                return false;
            }
        })
}


private void photoPopUp(Photo photo) {
    // Inflate the popup
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   MapActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.journal_single_image,     (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.single_image_popup));

    // show popup
    PopupWindow imagePopup = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 370, true);
    imagePopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


    // display the photo
    File imgFile = new File(photo.getPathOnDevice());
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_image_full);
    if (imageView == null){
        Log.d("Journee", "imageview is null");
    }else {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
}
```

and this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:id="@+id/single_image_popup">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image_placeholder"
    android:id="@+id/single_image_full"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.22" />

</LinearLayout>
```

clicking on a marker does open up my pop window, with the default image placeholder, but I cant get it to be replaced by my photo.

in the last lines of my code I get that imageView is null

thx